# How can I set up a connection between 2 phones so that they can send and receieve notification/messge to each other

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project that it should let one user send an partner invitation to another user, as long as the other user receieved and accept this notification, they are gonna be paired, and they will receieve other's notification in the future.

Comment: I will be appreciated for providing me a start point

Comment: give us some more info.  will phones be nearby (close to each other) or not? what kind of data? how large data transfer are you talking about? depending on data type and size, I can give you some suggestions

Comment: it won't be near by, the data will only be location, users will get notification if their partner goes to a certain location

Comment: Follow up with this @Unforgiven. http://www.ghacks.net/2014/01/09/ultrasonic-communication-chat-client-using-sound/